# Set AsciiDoc output directory

Tags: asciidoc

I want to output the final result into a specific directory. I have already check the command's help with no luck.

I also have searched the Internet, but also with no luck.

how do I achieve this?

**edit:**

It seems that I overlooked the `-o` option...

Comment: Are you using asciidoctor or asciidoc?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-D` option as specified in https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/cli/output-file/

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like asciidoc (the python implementation) has a way to specify an output directory, but as you mentioned the `-o` option will specify an output **file** as asciidoc won't run on multiple files in a directory you can make `-o` do what you want for the single file:

```
asciidoc -o new_dir/filename filename.asciidoc
```